# How to broadcast different slices for each row?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, slice, array-broadcasting, numpy-slicing

I'm operating on a numpy 2-d array and trying to find some way to access different slices per row. Preferably exploiting numpy broadcasting in such a way that I pass an array of slices like follows:

```py
A = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[1,4,9,16,25],[1,8,27,64,125]])
A[[2:,3:,4:]]
>>> array([[3,4,5],[16,25],[125]])
```

I know what I wrote above is bogus, but you get the point. I'd like to pass in an array t = [2,3,4] so that each member of that array (denote by t_i) results in t_i: (that member and a colon after).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is probably not possible with broadcasting. But a list comprehension may work:

```
np.array([a[i+2:] for i,a in enumerate(A)])
#array([array([3, 4, 5]), array([16, 25]), array([125])], dtype=object)
```